# Proper Redirect Inside Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Inside my controller I have the following:

```
  before_filter :authenticated?, :only => [:edit]

 def authenticated?
    if current_user != User.find(params[:id])
      flash[:alert] = 'Log in!'
      redirect_to login_path :status => 401
    end
  end
```

Now when I am logged in and I go to edit the user everything works, but when I go to edit a user I shouldn't be able to I get the following:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions", :status=>401}
```

Why is this? For reference I have included my rake routes below.

```
 users GET     /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
        POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user GET   /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET  /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
sessions POST  /sessions(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
new_session GET/sessions/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
   root        /                         {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
contact        /contact(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
  about        /about(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
   help        /help(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
 signup        /signup(.:format)         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
               /signup(.:format)         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
signout        /signout(.:format)        {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
 signin        /signin(.:format)         {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `redirect_to signin_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even see a `login_path`, you should be able to redirect to `signin_path`, though.

In any case, is the `:status` part critical to your needs?

Comment: Not really no. Thanks. I wish I could give you extra points for my stupidity!